# JS: Check for existence of deep object key and replace value

Tags: javascript, json, object, mutate

I am wanting to develop a function to check for the existence of a key within a deep object and then replace the value of that key with a data set from another object.

E.g.

```
var obj = {
    "id": 1,
    "component": "Preset 1",
    "priority": 1,

    "header": {
        "modeSet": 2
    }
}

const modeSets = [
    {
        "id": 1
        "name": "Mode Set 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2
        "name": "Mode Set 2"
    }
]

function obtainModeSets(obj){
   //...
}
```

When the function `obtainModeSets` runs I'd like to mutate `obj` so that the value of `modeSet` within `obj` equals `{ "id": 2 "name": "Mode Set 2" }`

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Is `obj` static data or it can be changed?

Comment: @NehaSoni Can be changed

Comment: Unless you mention what can be change in the `obj`, can't this work - `obj.header.modeSet = modeSets.find(item => item.id == obj.header.modeSet)`

Comment: The example I've given is simplified. In actuality there will be loads of ```obj``` objects that will come in many different forms with multiple modeSet keys in various places of the objects. I would like the function to find these modeSets and replace their values.

Comment: Replace the value of `modeSet` with its corresponding object in the `modeSets` array: `obj.modeSet = modeSets[obj.modeSet - 1]`?

Comment: So the value of `modeSet` in `Obj` is equal to the `id` property of an Object in `modeSets` from which the `name` should be added to `Obj`?

Comment: @DavidThomas exactly

Comment: Is my answer wrong ? @mellows

Comment: So, @mellows, could you add a clear explanation to your question, and show the *exact* result you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion like this

```js
const obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "component": "Preset 1",
  "priority": 1,

  "header": {
    "modeSet": 2
  }
}

const modeSets = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mode Set 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mode Set 2"
  }
]

function obtainModeSets(obj) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key === "modeSet") {
      obj[key] = modeSets.find(set => set.id === value)
      return
    }

    if (typeof value === "object") {
      obtainModeSets(value)
    }
  })
}

obtainModeSets(obj)

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I don't think they want to set `obj.headers.modeSet` but rather `obj.modeSet`

Comment: they said `so that the value of modeSet within obj equals { "id": 2 "name": "Mode Set 2" }`

Comment: @mellows Is this wrong ?

Comment: @unhackit no that's done it. Recursion is what I was looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the below code maybe solves your problem. I don't know what you mean exactly. But based on the showing example, I guess you need to replace your key with the id provided in the `modeSets`.

```js
function obtainModeSets(obj, key, cb){
  // loop through all possible keys
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
    if (key === k) {
      obj[k] = cb(obj[k])
    }

    // if the value of the key is object, just go inside
    if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
      obtainModeSets(obj[k], key, cb)
    }
  })
}

// you can call your function like this
obtainModeSets(obj, 'modeSet', (val) => {
  return modeSets.find(mode => mode.id === val)
})
```